# Get cell value and fill rows of new column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data looking like this:

```
Col1
time: 4
1
2
3
time: 7
4
5
6
time: 11
7 
8
...
```

I want to add a new column an make it to look like this:

```
Col1      Col2
time: 4   4
1         4
2         4
3         4
time: 7   7
4         7
5         7
6         7
time: 11  11
7         11
8         11
...       ...
```

So I want to grab the specific value from the rows "time: x" and put them in the rows of the new column until the next row with "time: x" appears. Any suggestions? I am not even quite sure if the value in the row is an integer or string.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
df['Col2']=(df.groupby(df['Col1'].str.contains('time:').cumsum())['Col1'].transform('first')
        .str.split(':').str[-1])
print(df)
```

---

```
        Col1 Col2
0    time: 4    4
1          1    4
2          2    4
3          3    4
4    time: 7    7
5          4    7
6          5    7
7          6    7
8   time: 11   11
9          7   11
10         8   11
....
....
```

**Explanation:**

First we create a helper series which returns True for all the rows having the word `time` and then cumulative sum them:

```
print(df['Col1'].str.contains('time:').cumsum())

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
```

Now we can treat this as individual groups so we groupby on this helper series and return the first value:

```
print(df.groupby(df['Col1'].str.contains('time:').cumsum())['Col1'].transform('first'))

0      time: 4
1      time: 4
2      time: 4
3      time: 4
4      time: 7
5      time: 7
6      time: 7
7      time: 7
8     time: 11
9     time: 11
10    time: 11
```

Once we have this result , we can chain `str.split` which splits the series on `:` and return the last element of the split by using `.str[-1]`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That, again, works perfectly. I would be really grateful if you'd find the time to explain in some words whats happening in the code so I can learn. I get some bits but not everything. Would be awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jailbone I have added a explanation , hope that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('dummy_data.csv')
print(df)
df['Col2'] = ''
fill_value = 0
regex_pattern = r'time: (\d+)'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if len(re.findall(regex_pattern, row['Col1'])) == 1:
        fill_value = int(re.findall(regex_pattern, row['Col1'])[0])
    row['Col2'] = fill_value
df
```

Output:

```
        Col1
0    time: 4
1          1
2          2
3          3
4    time: 7
5          4
6          5
7          6
8   time: 11
9          7
10         8
        Col1 Col2
0    time: 4    4
1          1    4
2          2    4
3          3    4
4    time: 7    7
5          4    7
6          5    7
7          6    7
8   time: 11   11
9          7   11
10         8   11
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, with a positive look behind assertion. What it means is if a number follows behind the string 'time: ', then extract it. After that, forward fill to get ur result:

```
 (df
  .assign(Col2 = lambda x: x.Col1.str.extract(r'((?<=time: )\d+)'))
  .ffill()
  )

     Col1      Col2
0   time: 4     4
1   1           4
2   2           4
3   3           4
4   time: 7     7
5   4           7
6   5           7
7   6           7
8   time: 11    11
9   7           11
10  8           11
```